# CSS rendered differently in chrome vs firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

In chrome (note the stats are shown properly in the gray box (bottom left corner))

[image]

However in fire-fox, the stats are positioned way below the box (bottom half hidden)

[image]

My CSS code is as follows

```
.stats_section {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -31px;
  margin-left: 76px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 24%;
}
```

How can I fix the CSS so that it works for both browsers?

Comment: are you using a reset framework of any kind? Also, are there any other styles applied to the elements (besides the one mentioned)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relative positioning can sometimes be pretty tricky so in this case I would definitely go with absolute positioning inside a container with explicitly set positioning.

For that you would need to set explicit positioning for the parent container containing `.stats_section` (`relative` would probably be fine in this case but if its already set to `absolute` it will also work).

```
.parent_container {
    position:relative;
}

.stats_section {
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0.7;
   height: 20px;
   bottom: -22px;
   left: 4px  
   width: 24%; /* You might want to use fixed width in pixels here */
}
```